# Java reflection get anonymous class' origin interface

Tags: java, swing, reflection

I have the following HashMap. Its purpose is to be used to invoke certain methods of classes extending JPanel. The method being the value in the HashMap and the parameter passed being the key.

```
HashMap<Object, String> methodMapper = new HashMap<>();

projectMethodMapper.put("Some title", "setInfoTitle");

projectMethodMapper.put(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("working");
    }
}, "attachListener");
```

This particular HashMap is to be used for a class called InfoPanel and it has the following methods.

```
public void attachListener(ActionListener al) {
    this.button.addActionListener(al);
}

public void setInfoTitle(String name) {
    ((TitledBorder) this.getBorder()).setTitle(name);
}
```

Later on I iterate through the keys of the HashMap.

```
InfoPanel infoPanel = new InfoPanel();

for (Object key : keys) {
    Method method = InfoPanel.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodMapper.get(key), key.getClass());

    method.invoke(infoPanel, key));
}
```

As you can imagine, there is no problem when the key is a String object, the problem comes when getDeclaredMethod searches for a method attachListener with parameter of type MainPanel$1 as .getClass returns MainPanel$1 because it's an anonymous class created on the fly. My question is - how do I find what interface is used for the creation of the anonymous class used for the object instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer to your question

> how do I find what interface is used for the creation of the anonymous class used for the object instantiation?

is in the code snippet below. But be aware, that your approach can be very problematic, and you should probably attempt to refactor it if at all possible.

```
public class Main {
    private static Class<?> getDeclaredInterface(Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        Class<?> objectClass = object.getClass();
        Class<?>[] implementedInterfaces = objectClass.getInterfaces();
        if (implementedInterfaces.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(objectClass.getSimpleName() + " implements no interfaces.");
        }
        if (implementedInterfaces.length > 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(objectClass.getSimpleName() + " implements multiple interfaces.");
        }
        return implementedInterfaces[0];
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Object object = (Closeable) () -> System.out.println("No-op.");
        System.out.println(getDeclaredInterface(object)); // prints 'interface java.io.Closeable'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use reflection for this. You can use a `List<Cosumer<InfoPanel>>`, which is bascially a list of functors that each take an `InfoPanel` as argument:

```
List<Consumer<InfoPanel>> commandList = new ArrayList<>();

commandList.add(panel -> 
    panel.attachListener(e -> System.out.println("working")) // using lambda for brievety
);

commandList.add(panel -> panel.setInfoTitle("Some Title"));
```

Then later on, when you create the `InfoPanel`:

```
InfoPanel infoPanel = new InfoPanel();

commandList.forEach(command -> command.accept(infoPanel));
```

Of course, this leverages Java8, but the same thing is possible with Java7 if needed.

---

If you insist on using reflection, you could create a datatype that stores the expected parameter types, as well as the method name and arguments:

```
class Signature {
    private final String name;
    private final Class<?>[] parameters;
    private final Object[] arguments;

    ...
}
```

Have a list of that:

```
List<Signature> signatures = ...;

signatures.add(new Signature("attachListener",
    new Class<?>[] { ActionListener.class },
    new Object[] { e -> System.out.println("working") }));
```

Then later on, use that parameter list for the lookup:

```
InfoPanel infoPanel = new InfoPanel();

for(Signature s : signatures) {
    Method m = InfoPanel.class.getDeclaredMethods(s.getName(), s.getParameters());

    m.invoke(infoPanel, s.getArguments());
}
```

Comment: Using reflection is not negotiable. The example is extremely simplified to show what the problem is. InfoPanel is not strictly InfoPanel, it's one of many classes and at the moment of iterating the HashMap, I don't actually have control over which class is being used, therefore I can't create List<Consumer<InfoPanel>>. It has to happen with reflection, alternatives are not possible. Good answer though, I hope it helps someone else in the future.  :)

Comment: @HristoValchevHristov But if the object is not strictly an `InfoPanel`, how/why are you calling the methods `attachListener` and `setInfoTitle` on it? Those calls would only work if the object actually has those methods. If they belong to a super type of `InfoPanel`, you could use consumers of that supertype instead. I still don't see why you would _have_ to use reflection.

Comment: Long story short: I am not calling them if they don't exist. There is a complicated answer and it really is irrelevant to the problem. The problem is I am not finding the method that receives ActionListener object.

Comment: @HristoValchevHristov I can not help you if I don't understand the problem. I can think of other solutions that would use reflection, but they could do the same thing without using it. I also don't understand why you use a map like this instead of a list of some data type that aggregates over the method name and the arguments.